# Why below code does not print binary representation of a integer?

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

Below code displays all 0's. I dont understand. It has to display properly according to my logic. What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void displayInBıtFormat(int);
int i, value;

int main(void){

puts("Enter an integer");
scanf("%d",&value);

printf("\n%d's bit representation is: ",value);
displayInBıtFormat(value);

getch();

}

void displayInBıtFormat(int val){

int mask=1<<15;

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    if (val&mask==1)
    {
        printf("1");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("0");
    }

    if ((i+1)%8==0)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    val<<1;
}

}
```

Comment: Try `if (val&mask)` without the equality comparison to 1. At no point will `0x1000 & <anything>` equate to 1. At best it will be 0x1000, so naturally all-zeros are printed.

Comment: I am so embarrassed. Thanks

Comment: It'd also be useful to assign `val<<1` *to* `val` (statement with no effect)

Comment: Ahh thanks. That is also a big mistake. Now program is working. Thank you for all repliers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
if (val&mask==1)
```

is wrong, the result of the bitwise-and will only be 1 when you're looking at bit 0 (the least significant bit).

Change it to:

```
if (val & mask)
```

that's enough, and totally correct.

Also, as pointed out in comments, this:

```
val << 1;
```

is throwing away the resulting value, you need:

```
val <<= 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

This comparison `val&mask==1` is not correct. If we have `i=1<<15` then `i&mask` will not be one but `1<<15`. Keep in mind bitwise `&` will produce an integer that has ones on all the positions where both operands have `1` thus the one in the result will be on 15th place. You can change the condition to `if (val&mask != 0)` or shorter `if (val&mask)`.